# Continuous integration with Access 2003 .adp from TFS 2010... is it possible?

Tags: ms-access, version-control, build, tfsbuild

I have a project that uses an Access 2003 ADP for the UI.  I've recently found out that by using the MSSCCI provider I can add this project in TFS and track changes do branching/merging. I would like to start doing builds in TFS but I'm not sure where to begin.  In office, after installing the source control add-in there is an option to build database from source control and this works.  I've done a little reading about the Office Interops and this project on codeplex:  http://buildmsaccessdb.codeplex.com/

After reading all of the materials I'm spinning a bit =D.  Does anyone in the community have any recommendations?  Are there alternatives for doing builds from TFS specifically for Office Products?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure where you question is here? As noted, MS Access for close to 18 years has supported the MSSCCI interface, and thus it up to you to pick <insert your favorite source control system here> and you are then off to the races.
<quote>"like to start doing buildins in TFS"</quote> Huh???? You don't do builds "in" TFS, you use your client based system, be it Visual Studio, MS Access, FoxPro, VB6 or whatever set of development tools you are using that can subscribe to the source code database or depository.

Comment: I would like to 'check in' my source and have an automated process build the latest version.  This is pretty easy to setup in TFS for visual studio projects.  I'm looking for a way to do it with an access adp.  This would be automating 'Create database from TFS project' option in access source control add-in.

Comment: Just found this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/accessdev/thread/40796119-cee1-4011-8ca2-e77ac6918e57 , perhaps I can add this as a build task in TFS.